# Would this be a duplicate?

Tags: support

I want to ask a question that is nearly identical to [Is there a spell managing program/app for D&D 3.5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/is-there-a-spell-managing-program-app-for-dd-3-5e) however about Pathfinder instead of 3.5

I am aware the two systems are very alike but I would like PF specific answer.

Would this question be a duplicate, or would it be OK due to being about a different system? If it would be a dup, what would be the best way to go about asking about Pathfinder specific Spell Managers?

Answer (score 7):

No, it would not be a duplicate, ask away.